Native messaging between browser and windows application
I want to send a message from a browser into windows powershell script and receive back a response.
Powershell script must handle diffrent messages from the browser and send back diffrent data to the browser depending on the message received.
I have created a browser extension and a powershell script in github https://github.com/sandanat/browser-app-native-messaging.
When I try to identify incoming message in powershell script app.ps1 with code
$Incoming = Read-Host
powershell script immediatly send a response to the browser extension with the incoming message sent from the browser.
Code for sending message from browser extension:
// catch message from content_script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  console.log("Sending data into native app", message);

  chrome.runtime
    // sending message into native app
    .sendNativeMessage("native.messaging", message)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Received data from native app on background.js:", data);
      return data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Sending data from background.js into content.js", data);

      return chrome.tabs.query(
        { active: true, currentWindow: true },
        function (tabs) {
          chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, data);
        }
      );
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});

Code of native app powershell script:
$Incoming = Read-Host
# $Incoming = '{"command": "test"}'

if ($Incoming) {
    $LogPath = "$PSScriptRoot/app.log"
    # Delete JSON Unicode escape notation
    $Formatted = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Replace($Incoming, '%\u0000\u0000\u0000', '') | ConvertFrom-Json
    # $Formatted | Out-File -FilePath $LogPath -Append

    if ($Formatted.command -eq "test") {
        $Data = @{
            text = "Response for test command"
        }
    }
}
else {
    $Data = @{
        text = "Response for NOT test command"
    }
}
 
$FormatData = $Data | ConvertTo-Json  -Compress
$Result = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new().GetBytes($FormatData)
$Writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter([System.Console]::OpenStandardOutput());
$Writer.Write([Int32]$Result.length)
$Writer.Write($Result)
$Writer.Flush()
$Writer.Close()

How can I handle diffrent messages in powershell script and send diffrent data depending on received messages from the browser?
Thanks!

Please, add a [mcve] of what you try to accomplish to the question.

What you want to do is to build a Controller like in c# (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs).  I would recommend either doing it in  c# or convert c# code to Powershell.
